# iPhoto refuses to open, even after deletion and reinstall

Tags: photos.app, crash, error

Here's the error message:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/NyxAudioAnalysis
  Referenced from: /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/Frameworks/iLifeSlideshow.framework/Versions/A/iLifeSlideshow
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/NyxAudioAnalysis: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/NyxAudioAnalysis: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Anyone know what I can do to rectify?

Answer (score 1):

Either copy a working version of that NyxAudioAnalysis.framework from a working machine or reinstall the OS.